# Correct order of using tranform, fit, and feature selection when there are separate training and test sets

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cross-validation, feature-selection, scikit-learn

I am not sure if I am following the steps correctly. Here, first I do a feature selection:

```
selection = SelectKBest(score_func=f_regression, k=15).fit(X,y)
X_features = selection.transform(X)
```

Then, I use cross-validation to calculate the `alpha_` with the selected features (`X_features`):

```
model1 = LassoCV(cv=10, fit_intercept=True,  normalize=False, n_jobs=-1)
model1.fit(X_features, y)
myalpha = reg.alpha_
```

Then, I train a new model with the calculated `alpha_` value:

```
model2 = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=myalpha)
model2.fit(X_features, y)
```

Finally, I use cross-validation to test the trained model on a new data set (test data):

```
pred_r = cross_val_predict(model2, X_test, y_test, cv=10)
```

I wonder if these steps are correct or not. For example, I am not sure if I need to do **fit & transform** on the test set as well. I appreciate any guidance.

**UPDATE**

I also wonder the scenario when there is no separate test set, and I need to do cross-validation on whole data:

```
selection = SelectKBest(score_func=f_regression, k=150).fit(X,y)
X_features = selection.transform(X)#

reg = linear_model.LassoCV(cv=10, fit_intercept=True,  normalize=False, n_jobs=-1)
reg.fit(X_features, y)

pred_r =  reg.predict(X_features)
```

With this code, I am afraid I am evaluating my model on the training set, which will result in biased results. Therefore, to decrease the bias and possibly overfit, instead of `reg.predict(X_features)`, I need to do a cross validation again for testing:

```
pred_r =  cross_val_predict(reg, X_features, y, cv=10)
```

I wonder if this would make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing model selection, the order of steps should generally be:

1. Decide which hyperparameters you want to cross-validate (based on prior knowledge, dataset size, computational budget...).
2. Fix hyperparameters that are not cross-validated.
3. Cross-validate remaining hyperparameters.
4. Evaluate model on a test set.

In your case, the hyperparameters are a) the feature set, and b) `alpha_` in the Lasso procedure. If you do not want to cross-validate the feature set (which, admittedly, is a hassle), then the order of steps you take is perfectly fine.

A few remarks / things to consider, unrelated to the order of steps:

- The Lasso does implicit feature selection by setting some coefficients to zero, so maybe you can skip the `SelectKBest` step.
- You do not have to refit the model, `LassoCV` does it automatically for you. So your `model1` and `model2` are identical.
- If you have a separate test set, you do not need cross-validation for model evaluation. Just call `model1.predict(X_test)` and compare to `y_test`. You should preprocess the test data in exactly the same way that you preprocessed the training data (i.e. do not `fit` new transforms, only apply old ones):

  ```
  selection = SelectKBest(score_func=f_regression, k=15).fit(X,y)
  X_features = selection.transform(X)

  model1 = LassoCV(cv=10, fit_intercept=True,  normalize=False, n_jobs=-1)
  model1.fit(X_features, y)

  X_test = selection.transform(X_test)
  y_hat = model1.predict(X_test)
  square_loss = ((y_test - y_hat)**2).mean()  # compute your favourite metric
  ```
- If there is no separate test set and you evaluate your model by CV, the one thing to bear in mind is that *everything* you do must be nested in a CV loop, including preprocessing, feature selection, etc. The [pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html#pipeline) structure makes this straightforward:

  ```
  from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

  pipe = Pipeline([  # enumerate all steps of the analysis here
      ('feature_sel', SelectKBest(score_func=f_regression, k=15)),
      ('lasso', LassoCV(cv=10, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False))
  ])

  yhat = cross_val_predict(pipe, X, y, cv=10)
  ```

Comment: I really appreciate your help Mary!!! Could you please have a look at the update in my question? I am not sure about my approach when there is no test data and when I need to do CV on whole data. Thank you again..

Comment: Hi, @renakre ;) Your first suggestion indeed evaluates on the training data, and, as you say, it is preferable to do a global CV. When you do this, make sure that all steps of your analysis are nested inside the CV loop (as explained in the answer), otherwise the results will be biased.

Comment: Thank you very much for updating your answer!!! I see that you used `pipeline`. So, in this case there is no need for calling the `fit()` or `transform()` methods

Comment: Exactly. `cross_val_predict` does so implicitly.